# maven: order of multiple profiles in a pom

Tags: java, maven, apache-axis

I have a pom with 3 profiles defined.
I want:

1. run "generate" profile always before all others (if needed)
2. run dev/normal profile based on e.g properties
   pom snip:

   ```
   <profiles>
       <profile>
           <id>generate-axis-stubs</id>
           <activation>
               <file>
                   <missing>target/generated-sources</missing>
               </file>
           </activation>
           <build>
               <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                       <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                       <configuration>
                           <generateServerSide>true</generateServerSide>
                           <generateServicesXml>true</generateServicesXml>
                           <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                           <packageName>${genclasses.package}</packageName>
                       </configuration>
                       <executions>
                           <execution>
                               <id>ESISGeneralSigningStatusUpdate_V1_0</id>
                               <goals>
                                   <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                               </goals>
                               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                               <configuration>
                                   <wsdlFile>${wsdl.src.dir}/ESISGeneralSigningStatusUpdate_V1_0.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                               </configuration>
                           </execution>
                       </executions>
                   </plugin>
               </plugins>
           </build>
       </profile>

       <profile>
           <id>normal</id>
           <activation>
               <property>
                   <name>!env</name>
               </property>
           </activation>
           <build>
               <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                       <configuration>
                           <excludes>
                               <exclude>**/JdbcDataServiceImplTest.java</exclude>
                           </excludes>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
               </plugins>
           </build>
       </profile>

   <!-- This profile should be used to run tests that requires access to DB It is activated in case system variable env=dev -->
   <profile>
       <id>run-db-tests</id>
       <activation>
           <property>
               <name>env</name>
               <value>dev</value>
           </property>
       </activation>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                   <configuration>
                       <includes>
                           <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                       </includes>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   </profile>
   ```

The problem is that on clean compile this works exactly every 2nd time.
I've enabled the -X debug and compared the output.
- is the failed, + is the one that worked.

```
@@ -1551,6 +1551,10 @@
 [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, 
generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, 
package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
 [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
 [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
+[DEBUG] Using mirror nexus (http://nexus.edb.com/nexus/content/groups/public/) for apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots).
+[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
+[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
+[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
 [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
 [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
 [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
@@ -1563,7 +1567,7 @@
 [DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
 [DEBUG] Project:       com.edb.esign:gssWsServer:2.3-SNAPSHOT
 [DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
-[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile]
+[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile, test]
 [DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [nexus (http://nexus.edb.com/nexus/content/groups/public/, releases+snapshots)]
 [DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [nexus (http://nexus.edb.com/nexus/content/groups/public/, releases+snapshots)]
 [DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run help:active-profile

1. after success it shows:
   The following profiles are active:

   - normal (source: pom)
   - nexus (source: settings.xml)
2. after the failed one it shows:
   The following profiles are active:

   - generate-axis-stubs (source: pom)
   - normal (source: pom)
   - nexus (source: settings.xml)

If I manually clean it and then compile - it works all the time. But why doesn't it work always for clean compile?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because profiles are evaluated exactly once. So the problem isn't `clean compile`, it's whether the folder `target/generated-sources` exists when you start Maven.

If it exists, `clean compile` has to fail because the clean deletes the folder but Maven doesn't care anymore.

Comment: Thx, that pretty much explains.. But how can I get what I want? Run "generate" before either of other two. I tried to change it to activeByDefault but now it won't run at all.

Comment: Why not always run the plugin? It should not do anything if the sources have already been generated :-/ If it always generates something, file an enhancement request or fetch the sources and fix it yourself.